# JavaScript function not being called onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following button in my JSP:

```
<button onclick="updateCart(${currentLineItem.product.id}, 'add');"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
```

The `updateCart` method takes 2 parameters, and is located in the `myJS.js` JavaScript file, which is located at the root of my web application under my js directory.

The import for the JavaScript file is:

```
<srcipt src="js/myJS.js"></srcipt>
```

The `updateCart` function makes an AJAX call:

```
function updateCart(productId, action) {
    var previousHTML = document.getElementById("mainDiv").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("mainDiv").innerHTML = "<img src=\"gif/ajax-loader.gif\" alt=\"Updating Cart...\">";
    var formData = "productId=" + productId + "&action=" + action;
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajaxCart",
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
            document.getElementById("mainDiv").innerHTML = data;
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            document.getElementById("mainDiv").innerHTML = previousHTML;
            alert('Problem occurred while updating cart.');
        }
    });
}
```

For some reason, when I click the button, nothing happens. I put an `alert` call at the beginning of the function to see if it was even being called, and it is not.

Comment: Do you get any messages in your _Console_?

Comment: You're using jQuery, so why not use proper event handlers instead ?

Comment: Did you try to pass productId with a value first to see if there is a problem?

Comment: What are "srcipt" tags?

Comment: What's the type of currentLineItem.product.id? Int? String? Something else?

Comment: Does anyone know why only the 1st time I click the button the function is called, but not on subsequent calls? Not even the ajax part, the function itself.

Comment: What is `${currentLineItem.product.id}` ??

Comment: If the button is inside #mainDiv, then you are "overriding" it with new elements inside the Ajax callbacks. In that case, you probably want to have a look at event delegation (jQuery makes that easy for you).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but there's some issues with your code at first glance:

1. It's `<script>` not `<srcipt>`
2. Your updateCart function has no end curly bracket (`}`)

Comment: Theres 2 hours I can't get back. The misspelling of script. The ending curly bracket is there.

Comment: I know that feeling...

Comment: It is strange though that when I click on the button the first time, the javascript function is called, but the 2nd time, nothing. I put an alert at the beginning of the function. I see it the first time, after that, I don't.